# ¿Cómo arreglar texto a entero en javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

Quiero traer un número de una etiqueta  html.

Sin embargo, en javascript no importa cuánto lo haya intentado, obtengo el error NaN y no entiendo por qué motivo.

¿Alguna idea de cómo arreglarlo?

```js
var texto = document.getElementById("texto_lineas").value;
var numero = parseInt(texto);
var botonjs = document.getElementById("boton");
botonjs.addEventListener("click", generadorNumero());

function generadorNumero() {
  console.log(texto);
  console.log("works " + numero);
  document.write(texto.value);
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>Cuantas lineas quieres <br>
        <input type="text" id="texto_lineas" />
        <button id="boton">A darle!</button><br><br>
        <hr>
    </p>
    <p>
        <script src="test.js"></script>
    </p>
</body>
```

Comment: Y por qué no usas un <input type=number">?

Comment: Lo utilice pero no me funciono, pero era por el error que me señalo y soluciono @pablo-lozano. Muchas gracias a todos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Tienes 2 errores:

```
// 1. Te quedas con el valor inicial, cualquier cambio posterior
// es ignorado.
var texto = document.getElementById("texto_lineas").value;
var numero = parseInt(texto);
var botonjs = document.getElementById("boton");
// 2. Estás ejecutando una llamada a generadoNumero() y, lo que se devuelve es 
// lo que se pasa como función a addEventListener
botonjs.addEventListener("click", generadorNumero());

function generadorNumero() {
  console.log(texto);
  console.log("works " + numero);
  document.write(texto.value);
}
```

La solución:

```js
//nos quedamos con el input
var texto = document.getElementById('texto_lineas');
var botonjs = document.getElementById('boton');
//pasamos la función sin ejecutarla
botonjs.addEventListener('click', generadorNumero);

function generadorNumero() {
  console.log('Texto:',texto.value);
  //+ es equivalente a parseInt
  let numero= +texto.value; 
  console.log('Como número con el que operar:', numero + 1);
  document.getElementById('resultado').innerHTML=numero;
}
```

```html
<body>
    <p>Cuantas lineas quieres <br>
        <input type="text" id="texto_lineas" />
        <button id="boton">A darle!</button><br><br>
        <hr>
    </p>
    <p id="resultado">
        
    </p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

Es porque al estar esos valores (texto y número) fuera de la función, solo se llaman una vez, cuando carga el archivo, no se llaman cada vez que presionas el botón por lo que quedaron seteados con lo que había al momento de la carga de la pantalla.
Para resolver eso, tu código debería ser así:

```
var botonjs = document.getElementById("boton");
botonjs.addEventListener("click", generadorNumero());

function generadorNumero() {
  var texto = document.getElementById("texto_lineas").value;
  var numero = parseInt(texto);
  console.log(texto);
  console.log("works " + numero);
  document.write(texto.value);
}
```

Comment: Ese código sigue teniendo un error, en la llamada a `addEventListener`

Comment: debes agregar el script debajo de tu html

Comment: No, lo digo porque sobran los paréntesis

Comment: como crees que deberia ser?

Comment: Mira mi respuesta: `botonjs.addEventListener("click", generadorNumero);`

Comment: si no pones esos () no estaras ejecutando la funcion solo estaras obteniendo su structura en formato de texto, toda funcion se invoca con su nombre seguido de parentesis

function pepito(){
   console.log(123)
}

pepito // pepito(){console.log(123)}

es distinto a :

pepito() // 123

Comment: Cuando se la pasas como parámetro a otra función, no quieres invocarla. Y la pasas como función, no se transforma a texto

Comment: toda la razon, nunca lo habia hecho. pero no recomiendo hacerlo pues asi sabes siempre que es una funcion, pues una persona podria confundirlo pensando que es una variable. pero gracias, nunca me habia fijado, la verdad es que deje de usar callbacks desde que llego await